# C# - connection leaking returning from class method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I has returning a connection from a class method in Connection class.  In my another class, I instantiate the connection class to open the connection.  I has close the connection as well but it seem like has connection leak.  Any idea how I can fix it.  My code as below

```
public class Connection
{
    private SqlConnection _oConn;

    public SqlConnection GetConnection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_oConn == null)
            {
            string sConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bplocator_database_connection"].ConnectionString;

                _oConn = new SqlConnection(sConnString);

            }
            return _oConn;
        }          
    }         
}
```

In another class file, i call this connection class

```
 private BPAdmin.data.Connection oConn
    {
        get
        {
            if (_oConn == null)
            {
              _oConn = new BPAdmin.data.Connection();
            }
            return _oConn;
        }
    }

public void getData
 {
    try
   {
        oConn.GetConnection.Open();
      //Do something
    }

   catch
      {
          oConn.GetConnection.Close();
      }
   finally
      {
          oConn.GetConnection.Close();
      }
 }
```

I found that this cause a connection leaking and it cause application pool reached max.  Any idea whats wrong and how I can fix it.  Please help!.

Comment: you also need to check the connection is opened or not. `oConn.State == ConnectionState.Open`

Comment: your code seems to be good except closing connection int `catch` but you might be using it in wrong way opening connection inside loop etc. You need to check that.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options

1. Use `using`  statement
2. In `finally` instead of `Close` call `Dispose`

Both solutions should fix the problem.

**UPDATE**: how to use using statement

Because `oConn` always return a new object in `getData` you can use following:

```
 public void getData()
 {
   try
   {
       using(var conection=oConn.GetConnection)
       {
             //execute your query
       }

    }
    catch
    {
          //do something to show user an error or just log it
    }
    finally
    {
         //you do not have to close connection because using statement will do this for you
    }
 }
```

Comment: how I can use the using statement in my situation?  Mind to share with me?

Answer (score 0):

`SqlConnection` is a disposable class, and you should dispose of it when you're done.

In short, have your class itself implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) (follow the example there. It's pretty textbook).

Answer (score 0):

```
   catch
      {
          oConn.GetConnection.Close();
      }
   finally
      {
          oConn.GetConnection.Close();
      }
```

take a look at this part, finally will happen whatever happens in try catch block, so remove

```
catch
  {
      oConn.GetConnection.Close();
  }
```

from your code

Comment: I use the finally to close the connection.  If I has any exception throw, what will happen without the catch block.

Comment: if any exception happens you will get to catch block in it you will close the connection, and then you will get to the finally and try to close the closed connection that will throw an exception!

Comment: so, I remove the connection close in catch block, right.  Is it my connection will do not has leaking after close in finally block?